# Outbound SMS issues

Tags: twilio, sms

We can't send any sms from our french number with twilio since this morning. Each time we try to send a sms, we have an error 30005. This is strange because all numbers we trying to send sms are reachable.
But we don't have any probleme receiving sms.
I tryed to contact the support but they are not answering for 12 hours
Do you have any ideas of what is the problem?
Thank you.

We tryed to contact the support but we didn't have any answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Status Page](https://status.twilio.com/):

> France Voice and SMS Carrier Partner Maintenance Aug 22, 13:00 - Aug
> 22, 18:00 Our Voice and SMS carrier partner in France is conducting a
> planned maintenance from 22 August 2023 at 13:00 PDT until 22 August
> 2023 at 18:00 PDT. During the maintenance window, there could be
> intermittent call failures to and from a subset of Twilio's France
> phone numbers and intermittent SMS delays delivering to and from
> France handsets via a subset of France longcodes. MAINTENANCE PERIOD
> US Pacific: Aug 22, 13:00 - Aug 22, 18:00 US Central: Aug 22, 15:00 -
> Aug 22, 20:00 US Eastern: Aug 22, 16:00 - Aug 22, 21:00 UTC: Aug 22,
> 20:00 - Aug 23, 01:00